# how to select row that doesnt have relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

given one to many relationship in Sqlalchemy:

```
class Menu(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'menus'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)

class MenuImage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(128))
    menu_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Menu.id))
    menu = db.relation(Menu, backref='images')
```

How do i select rows in Menu that doesn't have image. I am able to filter row that has image but not the other way. On flask-admin filter i will write as something like this:

```
class FilterHasImage(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value):
        // I dont understand where the 'query' came from
        if value == '1':
            return query.filter(self.column is not None)
        else:
           // HERE IS THE CODE I SHOULD PUT

    def operation(self):
        return 'Has Image'

    def __init__(self, column, name):
        options = (('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No'))
        super(FilterHasImage, self).__init__(column, name, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) for this. The documentation provides an example for *does not have any* case. With your model it might looks like:

```
q_nope = db.session.query(Menu).filter(~Menu.images.any())
for menu in q_nope:
    print(menu)
```

While for *has* you can do either of the below:

```
# get Menu items with images (using `.any()`)
q_does = db.session.query(Menu).filter(Menu.images.any())

# get Menu items with images (using inner join, which will filter implicitly)
q_does = db.session.query(Menu).join(Menu.images)
```

*I do not know what are the Flask-Admin filter implementation requirements, but home you can derive the right implementation from above.*